# ¿Por qué me da #VALOR al usar la fórmula SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO en la cual anido la formula MES?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy teniendo un error al utilizar la formula SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO, la cual adentro tiene la formula MES que intenta tomar el dato de una hoja contigua dentro del mismo libro.

Me da #VALOR diciendome "Los argumentos de la matriz de SUMIFS son de distinto tamaño."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Acá va una [PLANILLA EJEMPLO](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KSDUyOFprehmNB7bpgvcAfhb1Z1jDi95P80YF8jlIwg/edit#gid=39618403) para que puedan revisar y reproducir el error.

Lo que deseo es sumar en la hoja "Gastos Consolidados" los importes de gastos que están la hoja "Gastos Detallados", pero utilizando un criterio que filtre según el mes y el tipo de gasto.

Para ello, hago un Sumar Si Conjunto que solo sume el importe del gasto realizado si coinciden con el tipo (Supermercado, Otros, Comidas, Ocio) y con el mes (Enero, Febrero).

Comment: Podrías explicar que es lo que deseas realizar?

Comment: Perdón! Lo omití. Lo paso acá y lo agrego al detale.

Lo que deseo es Sumar en la hoja "Gastos Consolidados" los importes de gastos que están la hoja "Gastos Detallados", pero utilizando un criterio que filtre según el mes y el tipo de gasto.

Para ello, hago un Sumar Si Conjunto que solo sume el importe del gasto realizado si coinciden con el tipo (Supermercado, Otros, Comidas, Ocio) y con el mes (Enero, Febrero).

Comment: El archivo ligado ya no concuerda con la imagen. Ahora la celda seleccionada no devuelve error. Te sugiero que el archivo que vincules a una pregunta lo "congeles" es decir, no le hagas ningún cambio". Por otro lado, las preguntas deben ser lo más "autocontenidas" que sea posible para lo cual podrías agregar la fórmula, la definición de los rangos con nombre, datos de entrada de ejemplo y el resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola! finalmente, en el foro de google me dieron [una solución](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs-es/wYW0gIUVbg4/yXkmQyHtGQAJ).

Es por eso que una celda ya no coincide con la imagen, porque allí probé la solución propuesta. 

Dejo el enlace a la solución para que en el futuro, quién tenga un caso similar, pueda usar la solución de ejemplo.

Gracias a todos por su tiempo y sugerencias!

Comment: Gracia por compartir que has encontrado la solución. Lo mejor es que respondieras tu mismo la pregunta con la solución que has encontrado. Ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Es lo que venía a hacer luego de haberme cerciorado que todo funcionaba bien en mi archivo principal (no en el de ejemplo, que claro, esta recortado) 

En ese momento, me encontré con tu respuesta así que me pareció adecuado responderte al mismo tiempo que compartía la información recibida en otro lado.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es usar la función FILTER anidada dentro de la función SUMA (SUM) como [me explicaron en este otro foro](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs-es/wYW0gIUVbg4/nP9NeOToGQAJ).